# Lucene Index: Exclude certain terms

Tags: lucene

How can I exclude certain terms based on length? For example do not index terms less than 3 letters or more than 20 letters. Also exclude words starting with a number.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

`StandardAnalyzer` has a `maxTokenLength` property that you can set and I think it already eliminates tokens starting with digits. But, if you'll have more specific needs, you'll need to make your own `Analyzer` and possibly `TokenFilter`. Contrary to Lucene's docs, it is not "straightforward" to implement these classes due to the unusual coding patters stemming from the top-performance requirement on the tokenization procedure. For example, there is no way to just slightly modify the behavior of `StandardAnalyzer` by extending it, you must start from one of the base classes. If you extend the same class as `StandardAnalyzer,` you are creating a *reusable* analyzer where you must take additional care to meet its contract.

So, first try to throw together an analyzer from existing filters. For example, there is a `LengthFilter` provided in the core Lucene. That failing, implement your own filter and build it into your analyzer.

This might help you as a start in implementing both a filter and an analyzer:

```
public class MyFilter extends FilteringTokenFilter 
{
  private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

  public MyFilter(TokenStream in) { super(false, in); }

  protected boolean accept() {
    final int len = termAtt.length();
    final int d = termAtt.charAt(0) - '0':
    return len >= 3 && len <= 20 && (d < 0 || d > 9);
  }
}

public final class MyAnalyzer extends ReusableAnalyzerBase 
{
  @Override protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(
      String fieldName, Reader reader) 
  {
    final Tokenizer source = new LowerCaseTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_35, reader);
    return new TokenStreamComponents(source, new MyFilter(source));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write a custom token filter to do all this. Refer to http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html more details.